# meta_query not working in wp_query

Tags: php, mysql, printf, wordpress

My post type is `product`. I use a checkbox field with `meta key` is `ht_featured`, meta value when I `print_r` is array([0] => featured).
My WP_Query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'showposts'     => 12,
    'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                    'key'       => 'ht_featured',
                    'value'     => array('featured'),
                    'compare'   => 'IN'
            )
    )
);
```

It doesn't show any post.
I tried with `value => 'featured'` and `'compare' => 'EXISTS'` but it not working.

Answer (score 5):

WP_query needs to be passed in an array. use following code and let me know if any prob.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query (array (
        'post_type'     => 'product',
        'showposts'     => 12,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'ht_featured',
                'value'     => array('featured'),
                'compare'   => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ));
```

You can refer to the discussion at wordpress forum:

```
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-wp_query-meta_query-value-string-contain-in-key-string
```

Comment: Thank you. I added array but it not show any post.

I tried:
                $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_type'     => 'product',
                    'showposts'     => 12,
                    'meta_key'      => 'ht_featured',
                    'meta_query'    => array(
                        array(
                            'key'       => 'ht_featured',
                            'value'     => 'featured',
                            'compare'   => 'EXISTS'
                        )
                    )
                ));

Comment: remove meta_key line and try. cause its already there inside meta_query array.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing all of this into WP_Query as individual arguments when they should be contained in an array.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'showposts'     => 12,
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'ht_featured',
            'value'     => array('featured'),
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Can you clarify your point about the checkbox? I'd suggest simply updating 'ht_featured' with either 'yes' or 'no' when you save the product. Then change your 'value' in the meta query to 'yes' and remove the 'compare'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no php error?
I think WP_Query needs to be passed in an Array

```
  $the_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
      'post_type'     => 'product',
      'showposts'     => 12,
      'meta_query'    => array(
              array(
                      'key'       => 'ht_featured',
                      'value'     => array('featured'),
                      'compare'   => 'IN'
              )
      )
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem until I used the function get_posts() rather than creating a new WP_Query. See if that helps...